# editing a GUI in another python file

Tags: python, tkinter, import, module

I am creating a program that uses multiple python files. In the main file, i create root/canvas of the GUI. However, I need to be able to edit this canvas (add to it, clear it etc) in another python file. Is there anyway i can do this?

This piece of code is in the main (`menu.py`) program which contains the canvas and root of the GUI. It calls another function (`test()`) in another python file.

```
def Search_Book():
    from searchbooks import test
    test()
```

The `test` function belongs to the `searchbooks.py` file. I need this function to clear the canvas which is in the original `menu.py` file. Is there any way i can do this? If not are there alternative ways of structuring my program so that i can achieve the same goal?

```
def test():
    canvas.delete("all")
```

This piece of code provides the
[following error:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Sjm4T.png)

Comment: You can pass the canvas as a parameter of `test()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can totaly access the canvas from another file, but you must first import your menu.py file into you test.py file.The code below requires you to have menu.py file and the test.py(test.py is the file which you have your test() function in) file in the same folder.

```
# This is in the test.py folder
import menu
def test():
  menu.canvas.delete("all")
```

Or alternative you could import all the properties of your menu.py file into your test.py

```
# This is in the test.py folder
from menu import *
def test():
  canvas.delete("all")
```

Hope that this was helpful.

Comment: I tried this. However, when i import the menu file, it automatically executes the code, even though i haven't intentionally ran any of the functions inside menu.py

Comment: So let me understand.When you import menu the function Search_Book gets executed?

Comment: when i import menu in the test.py file, the menu.py file automatically executes. This means the whole GUI reopens. How do i stop it from automatically executing?

Comment: Mmm...Not sure why this happens but I will try to figure it out.

Comment: I think the reason is because you need to use the `if __name__ == '__main__':` to execute some code in your `menu.py` code. This will mean that code is not run unless is it is the file that is being executed (meaning it wont run from being imported)